Jetpack Compose adjust padding/scroll when keyboard opens
Im seeking to better understand IME padding in the context of keeping scrolled content visible when the keyboard opens. I have read again through https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/layouts/insets . I have updated my manifest file to include: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize".
I built a simplish example to play/experiment with:

The goal is that when I click on either text field in the card, and the keyboard appears, the entire card scrolls if necessary to stay visible. But when I click on either, I see this:

The content will slide up to make sure the BasicTextField is visible, but none of the rest of the card. I have thrown imePadding, imeNestedScrolling, and consumeWindowInsets(WindowInsets.ime) at multiple combinations of places in the compose hierarchy, but none seem to have any effect at all.
I begin to be skeptical that this is solvable? Dynamically adjusting the vertical height of something in a scrolled list will just change its height, but not its scrolled offset. And yet, clearly it is scrolling the list to keep the BasicTextField visible.
Here's the code (devoid of the various ime additions I've tried) used to produce:
@Composable
fun Screen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    LazyColumn(modifier) {
        items(ItemCount) { index ->
            EditableCard(index)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun EditableCard(index: Int, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    ElevatedCard(
        modifier = modifier.padding(16.dp),
        colors = CardDefaults.elevatedCardColors(containerColor = Color.hsv(360f * index / ItemCount, 0.5f, 1f))
    ) {
        var layoutBox = Rect.Zero
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(16.dp), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text("$index")
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(20.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.hsv(360f * index / ItemCount, 1f, 0.5f))
            )
            var text1 by remember { mutableStateOf(String.format("%02X", index)) }
            BasicTextField(
                text1,
                onValueChange = { update -> text1 = update },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(imeAction = ImeAction.Done)
            ) { innerTextField ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(color = Color.LightGray)
                        .border(Dp.Hairline, Color.DarkGray)
                ) { innerTextField() }
            }
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(20.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.hsv(((360f * (index + 8)) / ItemCount) % 360f, 1f, 0.5f))
            )
            var text2 by remember { mutableStateOf(index.toString(2).padStart(8, '0')) }
            BasicTextField(
                text2,
                onValueChange = { update -> text2 = update },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
            ) { innerTextField ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(color = Color.LightGray)
                        .border(Dp.Hairline, Color.DarkGray)
                ) { innerTextField() }
            }
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(20.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.hsv(((360f * (index + 16)) / ItemCount) % 360f, 1f, 0.5f))
            )
        }
    }
}

